# PHPUnitStaticDbConnectionListener does not implement the PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener interface"

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I installed a fresh version 3.2.5_demo of Symfony and didn't change anything on it.

When I Run `phpunit` I've get the following:

> Class
>   "\DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitStaticDbConnectionListener"
>   does not implement the PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener interface

These are two lines from "PHPUnitStaticDbConnectionListener.php" :

```
use DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\StaticDriver;
class PHPUnitStaticDbConnectionListener extends \PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a PHPUnit test listener that was written for PHPUnit < 6 with PHPUnit 6.